# Trim each column values at pandas

Tags: python, pandas, text-mining, strip

I am working on .xls files after import data to a data frame with pandas, need to trim them. I have a lot of columns. Each data starting xxx: or yyy: and in a column
for example:

1. xxx:abc yyy:def \n
2. xxx:def yyy:ghi \n
3. xxx:ghi yyy:jkl \n
4. ...

I need to trim that xxx: and yyy: for each column. Researched and tried some issue solves but they doesn't worked. How can I trim that, I need an effective code. Already thanks.

(Unnecessary chars don't have static length I just know what are them look like stop words. For example:

1. ['Comp:Apple', 'Product:iPhone', 'Year:2018', '128GB', ...]
2. ['Comp:Samsung', 'Product:Note', 'Year:2017', '64GB', ...]

i want to new dataset look like:

1. ['Apple', 'iPhone', '2018', '128GB', ...]
2. ['Samsung', 'Note', '2017', '64GB', ...]

So I want to trim ('Comp:', 'Product:', 'Year:', ...) stop words for each column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`pd.Series.str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) for this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([['Comp:Apple', 'Product:iPhone', 'Year:2018', '128GB'],
                   ['Comp:Samsung', 'Product:Note', 'Year:2017', '64GB']],
                  columns=['Comp', 'Product', 'Year', 'Memory'])

for col in ['Comp', 'Product', 'Year']:
    df[col] = df[col].str.split(':').str.get(1)

#       Comp Product  Year Memory
# 0    Apple  iPhone  2018  128GB
# 1  Samsung    Note  2017   64GB
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I didn't explain my problem clearly sorry. The columns unnecessary chars don't have static length. I mean for example: [xxx:abc yy:def ghi ...] So I don't trim any char at [2], trim first 4 char at [0] and trim 3 char at [1]. They are dynamic so I need to cut just ('xxx:' , 'yy:' ) chars.